# Elastic Easy Search Please provide an index for your component [no-index]?

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-easy-search

Despite carefully following the instructions on how to configure the [Elastic Search Package](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/getting-started/) to add **Search** functionality to my Meteor App, I keep getting this frustrating error message in my browser console:

```
details: undefined
error: "no-index"
errorType: "Meteor.Error"
isClientSafe: true
message: "Please provide an index for your component [no-index]"
reason: "Please provide an index for your component"
stack: "Error: Please provide an index for your component [no-index]
```

Following is my code:

**../imports/api/tasks.js**

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
import { Index, MinimongoEngine } from 'meteor/easy:search';

global.recipientsDetails = new Mongo.Collection("recipients");

global.recipientsDetailsIndex = new Index({
  collection: recipientsDetails,
  fields: ['recipientNumber', 'recipientAmount'],
  engine: new MinimongoEngine(),
})
```

**../client/main.js**

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Template.navigationMenu.helpers({

    enableButtonSearchResults: () => recipientsDetailsIndex,
});
```

**../client/main.html**

```
<template name="navigationMenu">
       {{#EasySearch.Each index=recipientsDetailsIndex}}

     <ul>
        {{#EasySearch.Each index=recipientsDetailsIndex }}
            <li>Recipients Number: {{recipientNumber}}</li>
        {{/EasySearch.Each}}
    </ul>

</template>
```

What I find strange is that, when I feed in the following code in my browser console:

```
var cursor = recipientsDetailsIndex.search("705087688"); 
// search all docs that contain "705087633" in the recipientNumber field.

console.log(cursor.fetch());
```

The following yeilds in the browser console:

```
[{…}]
 0:
  paymentDate: "2019-04-08 23:20:01"
  recipientAmount: "110"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087688"
  _id: "Wo4oZNzs5fLTqadcn"
```

The above results suggest that the Elastic search package is working and the fault is in the template, though I might be wrong.

Kindly help point out what I have missed or got wrong in the template or elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess here: But the http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/engines/ mention that there is a Elastic Search Engine and in your tasks file you use MiniMongoEngine...